# Is there any analogue of EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE in D

Tags: d

In C / C++ there are macros EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE. What are their analogue in D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined in D as well. Simply import `core.stdc.stdlib` to use them.

Comment: Also, in D, a successful exit is a regular return from main() and a failure exit is done with an uncaught exception (the runtime will catch it, print the message, then return the failure code).

Comment: I'm playing with WinAPI app. It has WinMain returning an int.

Comment: In that case, follow the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (scroll down to "Return value").

Comment: I've already read this one, thanks. I should return 0 if finished defore message loop and message.wParam otherwise. But message.wParam is simply argument of PostQuitMessage (commonly called from the window function) - the classic process' exit code.